# Disable button after submit with form that has PHP function. No jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a HTML form echoed in PHP, the form action calls a PHP function. I want to disable the submit button after its been clicked without using jQuery if possible.

```
#PHP
echo '
<form method="POST" action="' . phpFunction() . '">
    //form fields
    <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Enviar</button>
</form>';
```

I have tried using `onclick="this.disabled=true"` on the button, but it prevents the PHP function from excecuting.
What should I do to excecute the function and disable the button?

Comment: I'm curious, what's inside the function? It is just that, the `action` attribute is just the path to where it will send its data, so there is really no need to make it a function.

Comment: Just use plain javascript then? If you dont want jQuery :D

Comment: Sanitization, inserting into DB, but written as a function. Dont know why.

Comment: after submit set `document.getElementById("btnID").disabled = true;` it might help

Answer (score 1):

Use this simple code to disable submit button

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function form_submission(form_id, button_id) {
            $('#btn_add').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            document.getElementById(button_id).style.display = "none";
            document.forms[form_id].submit();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="submit.php" method="post" name="form_name" id="form_name">
        <input type="text" name="first_name" />
        <input type="text" name="last_name" />
        <input type="button" name="btn_add" id="btn_add" value="save" onclick="form_submission('form_name', 'btn_add')" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: umm...why would you hide button, the OP asked to disable it.

Comment: then don't use hiding part. you can use disable part

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("yourButtonId").disabled = true;`

Taken from here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_pushbutton_disabled.asp